# Invalid website URL for the localhost development in passportjs with Twitter

Tags: twitter, oauth, passport.js

i am getting  Invalid website url when trying to use localhost login  for Twitters oAuth

```
Website URL (required)
http://127.0.0.1:3000
Invalid website url
```

i have followed few links stating localhost won't work i used   http://127.0.0.1:3000  still i am facing the error  any help in using localhost

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the 127.0.0.1 IP address is correct?

Alternatively you could try

```
http://localhost:3000
```

or

```
localhost:3000
```